# File I/O difficulties in C

Tags: c, unix

I'm writing a version of the Unix `expand` utility that replaces tabs with spaces in a file.  To do this, I'm reading in each character and testing if it is a tab character.  If it is, it replaces the tab with the given amount of spaces, otherwise the character gets printed.

My main method goes like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
 FILE *fp;

 char *help1="-help";
 char *help2= "--help";

 //int spaces; //number of spaces to replace tabs

 fp= fopen(argv[1], "rw");
 parse_file(fp, 4);
 fclose(fp);

 return 0;
}
```

the parse_file method goes like

```
void parse_file(FILE *fp, int spaces)
{
  int i; //loop counter
  char c; //current character
  while (c!= EOF)
{
    c= getchar(); //get char from stream

    if (c=='\t') //if char is a tab
    {
        for (i=0; i< spaces; i++)
            putchar(" "); //replace with spaces

    } 
    else 
        putchar(c); //otherwise, print the character

}
```

}

When compiling, I get an integer from pointer without cast warning for `putchar(" ");` and the program hits a segfault when executing.

So, my questions:

1- What is the warning "makes integer from pointer without cast" all about?  What can I do to resolve it?

2- The code generates a segfault on execution with a text file passed in as an argument.  Is there anything in this code that would cause that?

Comment: You must use `' '` instead of `" "` to begin with.

Comment: By the way, if you are planning to run this utility to tidy up tabs from code then it almost definitely won't do what you expect. Tabs are not the same as four spaces, because they always stop at the next tabstop. So if the tabstop is set to 4 then lines starting tab, space-tab, space-space-tab or space-space-space-tab will all line up with each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You're calling `putchar` on a string (`" "`), but it wants a `char` argument (`' '`). (Actually an `int`, but only passing a `char` is safe.)
2. The segfault is probably due to the `fclose` on `fp`, which may be `NULL`. You should check the return value from `fopen`. The reason you only notice after `parse_file` is that it doesn't touch `fp` at all (it reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`). To use the stream `fp`, you should use `getc(fp)` and `putc(fp)` instead. (That still won't work because you'd overwrite the stream with more data than you're reading from it, so you'll get garbage out.)

In fact, the program is sure to segfault when no command line argument is given. Either `fopen` segfaults because it is handed the null pointer `argv[1]`, or it returns a null pointer itself.

When writing these kinds of programs, please adhere to the Unix philosophy and write them as [filters](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29): read from `stdin`, write to `stdout`. Don't modify a file in-place if you don't have to.

Comment: So how do I use stdin to open a stream to the argument file?

Comment: `fp = fopen(filename, "r"); if (fp == NULL) HANDLE_ERROR;` fill in the `HANDLE_ERROR` part yourself. Don't open for writing, it won't work for this program. Just write to `stdout` using `putchar`.

Comment: I might have misunderstood your question. If you mean, how to redirect `stdin` from a file, then run your program as `./myprogram < filename`.

Comment: Actually, you just answered my next question.  I didn't know you had precognition skills!  Thanks!

Comment: @Jason stdin is already open, as is stdout; just read from stdin and write to stdout.

Answer (score 8):

you must use

```
putchar(' ')
```

instead

```
putchar(" ")
```

Comment: You added a string with space instead of the character space.

Comment: Don't you mean `putchar(32)` ?

Comment: @Tim Post: no, of course not. `putchar(32)` is both non-portable and not clear.

Comment: What a bizarro question from a moderator.

Answer (score 3):

In C string literals are of type `char *`, a pointer to some area containing string characters.
`" "` is a string literal, not a character. Use `' '` when you need a single character

Answer (score 1):

As everyone else says, re. The use of char vs. string. As for the logic behind the actual error message you see, the string is a pointer to a const array of characters. Hence the error is saying it is converting the pointer to an int. Most of the char functions work with ints.

Answer (score 1):

To summarise the issues (I'm repeating stuff other people have said, but issue<s>s</s> 5 <s>and 6</s> <s>have</s>has not been mentioned so far):

1. `putchar()` does not take a string pointer as an argument but an int - the constant `' '` is an acceptable parameter
2. you don't check that `argc > 1` before using `argv[1]`
3. you don't check that `fopen()` successfully opens the file
4. `c` should be defined as an `int` since in some character sets `(char) -1` (0xFF) is a legitimate character and also the comparison `c == EOF` may fail if `c` is not sign extended
5. The first time through the loop `c` is used uninitialised and in the loop you also treat `EOF` as a normal character.  The normal idiom in C programs is

   ```
   int c;
   while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
   { 
       // do stuff with c
   }
   ```
6. You are getting your characters from `stdin` and not `fp` hence use `fgetc()` not `getchar()`

I think that covers everything.

To answer your explicit question, you get the warning "makes integer from pointer without cast" when an int is expected but you use a pointer (in this case the type of `" "` is `const char*`).

Comment: It doesn't cover the fact that his code doesn't actually comprehend what a tab character does.

Comment: @Jim Balter: you mean that tabs do not insert n characters but x characters where x is the right number of characters to get the next multiple of n in total for the line.

Comment: I mean that a tab moves to the next tab stop. You've described what the code needs to do to convert a tab to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to  what has already been said, getchar() returns int not char. EOF is an int constant. You will need to read the result from getchar() into an int, check for EOF, and if not found, cast the int into a char.

Comment: It isn't necessary to do any casting; the int will have the char value in its low bits, and it can be used anywhere a char is needed (other than taking its address).

Comment: @Jim Roughly spoken, yes. But your code would turn endian-dependent. printf("%c", getchar()) will for example display the symbol corresponding to EOF on a little endian machine, but the symbol corresponding to 0x00 on a big endian machine. Good practice is to always typecast to the indended type, that will solve a number of issues with implicit integer promotions as well.

Comment: That's nonsense. Chars are expanded to ints when passed as arguments, and that's what %c expects.